# Android not remembering which music app was in use last when pressing headset play/pause button

Tags: music-player, default-applications, hands-free

My phone has developed an odd and hard to reproduce problem lately.  I have been listening to a lot of audiobooks using BeyondPod.  Throughout the day, I often pause and resume the tracks using the play/pause button on the headset.  Usually this works without a hitch, but at random times it will launch the basic Android music player and start playing music, rather than resuming my audiobook where it was last paused.

When I listen to music, I use Rocket Player.  I have never intentionally launched the basic player.  I used to have random conflicts between BeyondPod and Rocket Player, but after being told by the Rocket devs that they couldn't control which player got control if I had headset controls enabled in both players, I just started switching off the headset controls in Rocket Player when I wasn't using it.  This worked for a while until recently when the basic player started launching instead.

I have noticed that it seems to forget that I was using BeyondPod primarily if it has been paused for a while and other (non-music) apps have been launched.  This leads me to believe that it is caused when BeyondPod gets deprioritized out of active memory.  However, I have been unable to force it to make this switch on purpose.

Is there any way to be able to select a system-wide default music player so it will stop launching the basic one?  I couldn't find a setting for this in my phone.  Alternatively, is there a way to mark an app as "higher priority" so it is less likely to be kicked out by other apps?  Any other thoughts on solving this?

---

- Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 (Sprint)
- Android: 4.4.2
- Rooted, but on stock Samsung image.

Comment: Clear Defaults, if any, in your installed music players whether System/User installed. You can do so  by going into `Settings -> Apps `, choose your app and clear Defaults. Now, open your preferred File Manager,  tap any music file, system will now show you options to open the file with shown music players, select the one you want for highest priority and choose Always. You're good to go. Post it as an answer it if works.

Comment: My current nexus 6p automatically opens google play music when pressing headset play button, instead of the previously used Smart Audiobook Player. Very annoying. My previous nexus 5 with android 7.0 did not show this behaviour. This is not about a default app for certain filetypes as the comment above suggests, it is about the default interpretation of a play button press. All I could do is disable google play music, but now the play button doesnt do anything unless I manually start an app. Did you ever solve this?